# Can I use Windows Server BMB to backup an entire Hyper-V host?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, raid, hyper-v

I have a Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V host server hosting a few VMs via Hyper-V. I need to do the following:

1. Backup/image the entire host server
2. Install new hard drives and create a new RAID array
3. Restore the backup/image to the new array
4. Pray everything works as it should

Would Windows BMB be sufficient to backup an entire host server? If I restore the server backup, will all the Hyper-V VMs still exist and work as they should? Any additional ideas or suggestions about this whole project are also appreciated.

Thanks for reading. Let me know if there's any detail I should add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use Windows Server Backup to backup the entire server including the virtual machines and the Hyper-V component, it's probably easier to either backup the virtual machines or export them, then rebuild the server from scratch and restore or import the virtual machines.

Comment: I'd be more keen to rebuild the host and import backups of the VMs if this were a personal or internal project. This is a client project and I'd be much more comfortable backing up their entire configuration to avoid any hiccups, even if it's a slower process. The total size of their host is only around 200 GB.

Comment: Exporting a virtual machine is a built-in capability of Hyper-V. It's intended to be used as an "enterprise level" method of moving virtual machines. I've exported/imported virtual machines across enterprise Hyper-V hosts and environments many times. Do yourself a favor, try your backup/restore method but export the virtual machines after you back them up. That way if there are problems with the restore you can simply rebuild the Hyper-V host and import the exported virtual machines.

Answer (score 4):

You normally backup VMs, it's must faster to provision new virtualization host from scratch, comparing to what you restore from backups.

Comment: I'd be more keen to rebuild the host and import backups of the VMs if this were a personal or internal project. This is a client project and I'd be much more comfortable backing up their entire configuration to avoid any hiccups, even if it's a slower process. The total size of their host is only around 200 GB.

Comment: Use bare metal backup for host and VM backup for VMs. It's actually more complex than just provision new host from scratch but as long as it works for you... Why not?